# Datatables trouble with fnGetPosition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that I'm using with the jQuery datatables API. In some of the cells in that table, I have links with the class `adder`. When the user clicks that link, I need to get the index location of that row, so that I can do some processing. I'm using the following code to test it out:

```
$('.adder').click(function() {
    alert(searchTable.fnGetPosition($(this).parent().parent()));
    return false;
});
```

My expectation based on the API documentation is that this would alert the index of the row in question. The parent of the `a` element should be the `td` element, and the parent of that is the `tr` element. However, when I click one of the links, what is actually happening is that the whole table is just refreshing. Nothing shows up in the javascript console...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the parent of the parent is a jQuery object and not a tablerow element or table cell element.  Since it appears you want the table row element then I would do something like this.

```
$('.adder').click(function() {
    alert(searchTable.fnGetPosition($(this).parent().parent()[0]));
    return false;
});
```

Here's the [documentation](http://datatables.net/api) for this api call as well in case you missed it.

Comment: Obviously, this is the correct answer. However, I'm wondering if you could give me a little bit more info on why a jQuery object is not equivalent to the element that has been selected? What else is in the jQuery object?

Comment: [Per jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) - ***A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM) elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a document.***  I definitely recommend on reading through the documentation on the jQuery object to understand what's there.

Comment: Interesting... so even if you've selected out a single DOM element, the jQuery object is more or less an array of elements with a length of 1. Thanks!